# Push-Server for iPhone: Which files I need on the PHP server?

Tags: php, iphone, certificate, push

I wanna have a push function on my app.
My app works with a MySQL Database from my homepage to read and send private messages.

I have the client side functions working perfectly:
I call the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken and write the decide token in the database.

Now my problem is my php site.
I get my code on this homepage:
http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2009/04/apns-client-development-certificate.html

But i´t didn't work.
It seems I need a lot of data / files on the same folder like the php-file is.

Can someone tell's me which files I need there?

(I am in a very big certificate and key-chaos, I needed around 10 hours to make the delegate for didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken working...)

Any help is welcome!

Comment: If you are game for another tutorial try http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at EasyAPNS.com
They have code already built out, an installation video, and more. They are very helpful.

[**http://www.EasyAPNS.com**](http://www.EasyAPNS.com)

When you get your server ready, and need help with creating the .pem files... 
take a look here: **http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/**